# Renaming the last created file with CMD / batch file (append suffix to original file name)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm trying to rename the last created file (only that file) in a directory full of files using a batch file.

The directory has files like this:

```
2020-06-21 23-56-26.mp4
2020-06-21 23-54-30.mp4
2020-06-21 23-48-40.mp4
2020-06-21 23-34-06.mp4
```

I want to take the last created file and append a suffix to the existing filename.

So for example `2020-06-21 23-56-26.mp4` becomes `2020-06-21 23-56-26_test.mp4`

I've found a lot of examples online, however I'm having some problems.

**Test 1:**

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od /t:c "C:\vids\*.mp4"') do set LAST=%%i
echo ren "C:\vids\%LAST%" "%%~nLAST_test%%~xLAST"
```

This almost does what I want, but the renaming section `"%%~nLAST_test%%~xLAST"` doesn't work. It seems like the variable substitutions are being ignored.

I get the output: `ren "C:\vids\2020-06-21 23-57.mp4" "%~NLAST_test%~XLAST"` which means the file gets literally renamed **%~nLAST_test%~xLAST**

**Test 2:**

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od /t:c "C:\vids\*.mp4"') do echo ren "%%~a" "%%~Na_test%%~Xa"
```

The variable substitutions used in this renaming command works, however it renames *every* file in the folder, as opposed to only the most recently created one.

Am I missing some brackets or other syntax?

Comment: On **Test 1**: the [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) are limited to `for` meta-variables and argument references, but they cannot be used for normal environment variables…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is:

```
@for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\vids\????-??-?? ??-??-??.mp4" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do @ren "C:\vids\%%I" "%%~nI_test.%%~xI" & goto :EOF
```

The file names with date/time in file name in international date format makes it possible to let **DIR** output the file names matching the wildcard pattern ordered reverse by name which results in getting output first `2020-06-21 23-56-26.mp4`.

**FOR** runs in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments. So executed is with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\vids\????-??-?? ??-??-??.mp4" /A-D /B /O-N 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in specified directory `C:\vids` for

- just files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `????-??-?? ??-??-??.mp4` and
- outputs to **STDOUT** in bare format because of option `/B` just the file names without path
- ordered reverse by name because of option `/O-N` which means in this case the MP4 file with newest date/time in file name first.

It could be that **DIR** does not find any file matching these criteria in which case **DIR** would output an error message to **STDERR** which is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself after finishing the execution of **DIR**.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here. All other lines would be split up by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. This split behavior is not wanted here as the file names definitely contain a space character. For that reason the option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters which disables line splitting behavior completely and so the entire file name is assigned to specified loop variable `I`.

**FOR** with option `/F` would ignore also lines on which first substring after splitting the line up starts with a semicolon which is the default end of line character. The option `eol=|` redefines the end of line character to a vertical bar which no file name can contain ever. `eol=|` is not really needed here as no file name starts with a semicolon.

The first file name output by **DIR** is assigned completely to loop variable `I` and **FOR** runs the command **REN** to rename the file with appending `_test` left to the file extension.

**FOR** would process next the next file name which is not wanted in this case. For that reason `goto :EOF` is added as second command to execute unconditionally after command `ren` to exit batch file processing.

It would be also possible to use something like `goto FileRenamed` and have as one of the next lines a line `:FileRename` to just exit from the loop and continue processing the batch file with the line below the line with `:FileRename`, for example:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\vids\????-??-?? ??-??-??.mp4" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do ren "C:\vids\%%I" "%%~nI_test.%%~xI" & goto FileRenamed
echo ERROR: Found no MP4 file in folder C:\vids to rename!
echo(
pause
exit /B

:FileRenamed
echo Newest file renamed, continue batch file processing ...
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`

Comment: This appears to work, but I don't understand why you use ```/O-N``` for the ```dir``` sort option instead of ```/O-D```. It's my understanding that ```N``` is for names whilst ```D``` is for date & time. Also you have a slight error with ```"%%~nI_test.%%~xI"```, the ```.``` isn't needed there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @crackerbear I have explained in my answer why in this case with all files names containing date/time in international format the option `/O-N` (ordered reverse by name) is used instead of `/O-D` (ordered reverse by date) with `/TW` (last modification time) or `/TC` (creation date of the file in this directory). It is of course up to you to use `/O-D /TW` or `/O-D /TC` instead of `/O-N` if you want to ignore the date/time in file name and use last modification date or creation date of file in directory `C:\vids`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od /t:c "C:\vids\*.mp4"') do echo ren "%%~a" "%%~Na_test%%~Xa"
> ```
>
> *The variable substitutions used in this renaming command works, however it renames *every* file in the folder, as opposed to only the most recently created one*.

Assuming the above works as described (which is not obvious since there seems to be more context missing), try the following to reverse the `dir` order and `ren` the *first* item, only.

```
set "DONE="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /t:c "C:\vids\*.mp4"') do if not defined DONE set "DONE=1" & echo ren "%%~a" "%%~Na_test%%~Xa"
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   As pointed out in a comment, OP's code quoted above only worked if the current directory was `C:\vids` at the time the `for` loop was executed, otherwise `ren` would be looking for the `%%~a` file in the wrong directory.

That unnecessary assumption can be removed, either by replacing `"%%~a"` with `"C:\vids\%%~a"` on the `ren` line, or by temporarily making `C:\vids` the current directory as follows.

```
pushd "C:\vids"
set "DONE="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /t:c "*.mp4"') do if not defined DONE set "DONE=1" & echo ren "%%~a" "%%~Na_test%%~Xa"
popd
```